# Create form which redirects to site in network?

Tags: php, customization, multisite

Just created a page in my multisite network where the user can input a sitename and be redirected to the site.
This works very well, but if there is a typo or if they enter a site that doesn't exist it will still redirect them.

Is it possible to do a check against the sites in the network to see if it exists before redirecting, and if not, output an error?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<?php
if ( ! empty( $_POST['sitename'] ) ) {
    $main_site_url = network_site_url();
    $domain        = preg_replace( "/^https?:\/\/(www)?/", '', $main_site_url );
    $domain        = preg_replace( "/\/u\//", '', $domain );

    $path = preg_replace( "/\//", '', trim( $_POST['sitename'] ) );
    $path = preg_replace( "/^(.+)$/", "/u/$1/", $path );

    $sub_site_url = "https://" . $domain . $path;

    // If the sitename does not exist.
    if ( ! $blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url( $domain, $path ) ) {
      wp_die( 'Sitename does not exist.' );
    } 
    else {
      wp_redirect( $sub_site_url );
      exit();
    }
} ?>
<form name="linkform" id="linkform" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <label for="sitename">Site Name:</label>
        <br><input type="text" name="sitename" id="sitename" value="" size="50"/>
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" class="submit" value="Go"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a validation through `get_blog_id_from_url($domain, $path)` function, assuming you are using directories and NOT subdomains. Otherwise, `$path` is not required.
See code and comments below.

```
<?php
if ( ! empty( $_POST['sitename'] ) ) {
    $main_site_url = network_site_url( '/' );
    $domain        = preg_replace( "/^https?:\/\/(www)?/", '', $main_site_url );

    $path = preg_replace( "/\//", '', trim( $_POST['sitename'] ) );
    $path = preg_replace( "/^(.+)$/", "/$1/", $path );

    // If the sitename does not exist.
    if ( ! $blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url( $domain, $path ) ) {
        // Perform whatever you want here...
        wp_die( 'Sitename does not exist.' );
    } else {
        wp_redirect( get_site_url( $blog_id ), 302 );

        exit;
    }
} ?>
<form name="linkform"
      id="linkform"
      method="post"
      action="">
    <p>
        <label for="sitename">Site Name:</label>
        <br><input type="text" name="sitename" id="sitename" value="" size="50"/>
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" class="submit" value="Go"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Put the PHP code plus the form HTML in the same place/page.

Comment: Just tried it out, and it doesn't have any effect at all?

Comment: @joq3 my snippet handles requests that have a wrong sitename. Did you test a wrong sitename and nothing happened? Also, you have to make the request through the form.

Comment: I tried it together with the code above, it should work when I enter a wrong site name in this input and press submit right?

Comment: @joq3 check my answer again, let's try a different approach.

Comment: It is better, but I get `Sitename does not exist.` even if I input a correct sitename

Comment: What is your main domain? And an example of sitename?

Comment: It is not live, but say domain is example.com/ and site name is test-1b so the address is example.com/test-1b

Comment: @joq3 I've changed the code again, give it another try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90433/discussion-between-filipecsweb-and-joq3).

Comment: Tried it again, still got the same issue as before :(